# Changing user passwords under Kerberos/LDAP

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap, kerberos, password-reset

I've set up Kerberos/LDAP on Ubuntu 11.04 Server according to [this guide.](http://www.danbishop.org/2011/01/31/ubuntu-10-10-sbs-small-business-server-setup-part-1-dhcp-and-dns/) My client machines are auto-mounting NFS volumes from the server using krb5. All is good: Users can log in to any of the machines in the office and their home directories auto-mount when they do.

**A user has forgotten his password. How do I -- root -- reset it?**

It seems to me that the password must be reset both in Kerberos and in LDAP, but I haven't been able to figure out how. Things I've tried:

1. `ldappasswd` - User can successfully log in but their home directory does not mount.
2. `ldapsetpasswd` - Same.
3. `kinit; passwd` - My understanding is that passwd hooks PAM and therefore it may be the one-stop-shop that I'm looking for to get this done. It keeps asking me -- rather cryptically, I might add -- for "Current Kerberos password." None of the usual suspects seem to work.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not tamper with the ldap password. It's probably `{SASL}user@DOMAIN.TLD`, which is what it *always* should be.

You should use `kadmin`.

You do not need to be root, just have the right privileges with the KDC.

example:

```
self@notakdc ~ $ kadmin
Authenticating as principal self/admin@DOMAIN.TLD with password.
Password for self/admin@DOMAIN.TLD: 
kadmin:  getprivs
current privileges: GET ADD MODIFY DELETE
kadmin:  cpw someuser
Enter password for principal "someuser@DOMAIN.TLD": 
Re-enter password for principal "someuser@DOMAIN.TLD": 
Password for "someuser@DOMAIN.TLD" changed.
kadmin:  quit
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with kpasswd? Also, if you happen to use Heimdal instead of MIT Krb, there is a nifty overlay for OpenLDAP that keeps the LDAP, Samba and Kerberos passwords in sync if you use the Modify Password LDAP exop.

Comment: `kpasswd` requires knowledge of the old password.